# Problems connecting Remix with Web3 Provider

Tags: remix

[image]

Trying to connect to my ethereum private instance (CentOS VirtualMachine) with Remix IDE I´m getting a error and I don´t now how to solve it. Using geth in the power shell i can conect but in via web I can´t.

Searching in the internet people says to change the remix url from https to http. But instead of that still having the issue

[image]

Any idea about what I can doing bad?

**EDIT**

If I connect with Ganache it works. What can be bad in my VM ?

Comment: Does any error appear in the javascript console?

Comment: Yeah men in the console appear the problem. Thank you. Two head (ore more) think more than one. jjj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Remix doesn´t allow diferent origin connection. So disabling the CORS I solve the issue. Simply that.

I use a Chrome extension to manage that.

Answer (score 1):

Remix says that there is nothing running on that port, or there is no response, usually, all RPC calls that don't come from localhost are rejected for security purposes, but since you are using putty I assume you are using ssh to connect to the VM.

If you are doing so, the easiest and safer thing to do is an ssh tunnel, which will redirect the traffic from your local RPC port to your vm's RPC port.

`ssh -f -N -L 22000:localhost:22000 sshUser@virtualMachineIP` + add keys if connection is rejected

Once you have the tunnel, in remix you can try to connect to

`http://localhost:22000`

Comment: Is the same ssh tunnel to the virtual box 
forwarding of ports no? Because that I have solved here. https://imgur.com/a/hRuuRan  I can´t understand why in my host machine I can connect with geth and in remix I can´t.

Comment: My theory is that you can't connect from your host machine to your VM in that port, try to execute a curl in your terminal localhost to check this `curl --data '{"method":"web3_sha3","params":["0x68656c6c6f20776f726c64"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
` and see if you can connect

If you can't, try the proposed solution

Comment: Im doing `curl --data '{"method":"web3_sha3","params":["0x955070fb433a78ece00a3ac822be5ee83b8a4a49"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:22000` but i´m not doing in the god way I think. But if with the PowerShell I can connect via geth from my localmachine to virtual machine that haves to work. Is my curl command bad formed??

Comment: Your command works on linux and mac (Don't have a windows machine), here is using wget `wget --quiet \
  --method POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Postman-Token: 5d27214c-9b5f-4353-8fc2-00b6b8cd3377' \
  --body-data '{\n    "method": "eth_getTransactionReceipt",\n    "params": [\n        "0xd081052e1aeeec01605f5ef29d18ddfb3360f46254d2cb72afe200311c24f99a"\n    ],\n    "id": 1,\n    "jsonrpc": "2.0"\n}' \
  --output-document \
  - http://3.8.52.222:8549`

Comment: And no, with geth attach you are connecting to your node, so the petitions to the node come from localhost, just try to do the ssh tunnel

Answer (score 0):

please try browsing http://remix.ethereum.org, cause your provider is http and not https

Comment: I do but the problem persist